# Non-symmetric example where Fubini's theorem fails but the iterated integrals are equal

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I was looking for measurable functions $f\colon \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$, for which the iterated integrals $$\int_{\mathbb R} \int_{\mathbb R} f(x,y) \, dy \, dx \quad \text{and} \quad \int_{\mathbb R} \int_{\mathbb R} f(x,y) \, dx \, dy $$
exist, are finite and equal, but yet $f$ is not integrable with respect to the $2$-dimensional Lebesgue measure, that is
$$\int_{\mathbb R^2}\lvert f(x,y) \rvert \, d(x,y) = \infty. $$
The standard (and the only I could find) counter example seems to be
$$f(x,y) = \frac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}, \quad x,y\in [-1,1].$$
My problem with this is twofold:

- $f$ satisfies $f(x,y) = f(y,x)$, which (if I do not miss something) makes it obvious that the iterated integrals must be equal (without even calculating them),
- since $f(-x,y)=-f(x,y)$ and $f(x,-y)=-f(x,y)$, the inner integral respectively vanishes because of symmetry reasons.

I wonder if there are more interesting functions that do not satisfy one (or both) of the two points above, but yet provide a useful example for the original problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A way to build such an example if to consider two functions $g :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $h :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ for which $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}}g $ and $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}}h $ converge but $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}}|g| $ and $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}}|h| $ don't ; and consider $f : (x,y) \mapsto g(x)h(y)$.

One can take for example :

$$f(x,y) = \left\{ \begin{array}{lll} \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x} \dfrac{\cos(y)}{y} &\text{if } x> 0 \text{ and } y>1 \\ 0& \text{otherwise.} \end{array}\right.$$

Comment: But $g$ and $h$ are not Lebesgue integrable on $\mathbb R$, right? So their Lebesgue integrals are not defined.

Comment: Indeed there are not. I didn't think you needed them to be,as which such a function $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x,y)\, dx$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x,y)\, dx \,d y$ exists even if the functions considered are not Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: If you consider Riemann integrals in your example, then it should work (and indeed is a nicer example than the standard one). But I would like to see something with Lebesgue integrals (as should be natural when working with Fubini).